# Invalid update SQL in DataGrip

Tags: mysql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I wrote a MySQL update SQL on my DataGrip to update the wrong data:

```
update common_express_track set step = 135 where express_id in (33, 235, 237) and business_source = 0 and step = 0 and content = 'Out For Delivery' order by content;
```

I executed it, the console showed that "61 rows affected in 7s 530ms" and then I executed an another query statement to make sure the data has been modified.

```
select * from common_express_track where express_id in (33, 235, 237) and business_source = 0 and step = 0 and content = 'Out For Delivery' order by content;
```

Then the console shows that "0 rows retrieved in 3s 751ms".

But when I restart the DataGrip and execute the query statement again, I got 61 rows, that means the update statement didn't work, I don't know why, is it because the cache or something?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: use mysql console and check it there

Comment: Your `SELECT`'s `WHERE` contains `step=0`,while the `UPDATE` set it to 135....

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto - yes, but rest of question explains why, it is ok

Comment: In sentence ` but when I restart the datagrip and execute the query statement again,` - do you mean second query?

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "restart the datagrip"?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I mean, I closed the datagrip and open it again, and then I executed the query statement to make sure the data has really changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute queries you should use `Autocommit`

[image]

Then by clicking on table in database view you will see `refresh`

[image]

Try use `Autocommit` with your query and `refresh` when you browse data. It should help.

Comment: OK! It works, I changed the Transaction Control option to Auto and this time the data is really modified. Thank you very much!  BTW, can you please tell me the difference between the manual option and auto option?

Comment: Without auto commit you should click commit to really execute your query, but you have also possibility to rollback. I recommend use this option on production database (if you do not selects before update), but when you develop it is simpler to use auto commit and confirm any query, then you will not forget about this.

Comment: Auto and Manual mode:
Submit button or ⌘Enter → submits your data, which means that your local changes(they are highlighted) are submitted to the database. If you are in the Manual mode this transaction is not committed. 
Revert Selected from the context menu or ⌘⌥Z (it used to be ⌘Z , but Revert isn’t Undo, right?) on selected rows → reverts unsubmitted local changes of the selected rows.

Comment: Only in Manual mode: 
Commit button or ⇧⌘⌥Enter → commits the transaction. If you have unsubmitted local 
changes (again, they are highlighted) they will be automatically submitted before the commit. 
Rollback button → rolls back transaction if it’s uncommitted.